# How do I get a substring of a multi line string in Python?

Tags: python, string, substring

Here's my code:

```
some_string = """
Blah blah 1: blah blah
Blah blah 2: blah blah
Blah blah 3: blah blah
Blah blah 4: blah blah
"""
```

I want the output to only print from the colon to the ending of a line. Like this:

```
: blah blah
: blah blah
: blah blah
: blah blah
```

This is what I tried till now:

```
print(some_string.count(":"))
print(some_string.count("\n"))
print(some_string[6:21])
```

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [regex](https://www.regextester.com/).

```
import re

some_string = """
Blah blah 1: blah blah
Blah blah 2: blah blah
Blah blah 3: blah blah
Blah blah 4: blah blah
"""

a = re.findall(r'\d(.+)',some_string)

for i in a:
    print(i)
```